# Manage roles users - [Angular]

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-cli

I want to manage users in my project so I tried this method but doesn't work ps: roles of current user is ROLE_MEDECIN
by the way I'm using angular 10

**TokenStorageService**

```
public getToken(): string {
    return sessionStorage.getItem(TOKEN_KEY);
  }
```

**Role.enum**

```
export enum Role {
    user = 1,
    admin = 2,
    ROLE_MEDECIN = 3,
    patient = 4,
    aideSoignante
  }
```

**code html and ts**

```
<span class="badge badge-danger" *ngIf="isMedecin">Admin</span> 
     
     currentUser : any; 
    ngOnInit(): void {
    
          this.currentUser = this.token.getUser();
    }  
     get isMedecin(){
          return  this.currentUser && this.currentUser.roles === Role.ROLE_MEDECIN;
        }
```

Comment: `currentUser.roles` (being plural) being potentially equal to `Role.ROLE_MEDECIN` (being singular) is a code smell

Comment: @Taplar yeah roles its an array of roles[{ id, name}]

Comment: Right, so your equality check isn't going to work, eh?

Comment: @Taplar yeah that's not working I don't know how can I fix it

Comment: How do you check if a value exists inside an array?  Also please edit the question to provide an example of the structure of the `roles` variable

Comment: I update my quest

Comment: That's the enum, which while helpful, doesn't show what the `roles` array looks like

Comment: no roles in backend its an array here in frontend I used enum

Comment: You said `this.currentUser.roles` was an array...